# Grep with regular expression returns everything

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to to get the date from the linux command "passwd". What im doing is this, i am storing users in the array @user and i want to run the command "passwd -S" on every user. When i i run "passwd -S user1" it returns this:

```
user PS 2016-02-16 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)
```

I came up with a regular expression to only get the date from that string, the regex looks like this:'

```
\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

However when i combine that with grep i cannot seem to get it to work, it still outputs the full output from the "passwd" command. Here is the code:

```
PasswordAge();

sub PasswordAge {
    for my $loop (@user) {
        my $pass =qx(passwd -S $loop);
        my @splitpass = grep {/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/} $pass;
        print @splitpass;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) returns all things that match the supplied pattern `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/`. Since each output of `passwd -S <username>` matches that pattern, this means that all results will be returned. If you want to extract *only* the date you could/should use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) and a regular expression capturing group.

Comment: You got nice solutions but note a new one, with the whole record built in one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[grep](http://p3rl.org/grep) selects elements of a list. If you want to match a part of a string, don't use `grep`, use matching:

```
sub PasswordAge {
    for my $user (@users) {
        my $pass = qx(passwd -S $user);
        my ($splitpass) = $pass =~ /(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/;
        print $splitpass;
    }
}
```

The parentheses around $splitpass force list context to the assignment, in which the matching returns the captured matches. That's why I surrounded the regex in parentheses - they create a capture group.

Comment: This worked great, the only problem im having now is that i want the output to match each user. So like this:

user1:2016-02-16

user2:2016-01-12

I tried using "print "$splitpass\n". $user" but that didn't turn out correct.

Comment: So just `print "$user:$splitpass\n"`?

Answer (score 2):

While you *could* use a regular expression in this situation, you don't really need to. You could just as easily use [`split()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html):

```
my $pass = 'user PS 2016-02-16 0 99999 7 -1 (Password set, SHA512 crypt.)';
my @parts = split(' ', $pass);
print "[$parts[2]]\n";
```

Or:

```
my $date = (split(' ', $pass))[2];
print "[$date]\n";
```

Output:

```
[2016-02-16]
```